# How do you add a badge to a website's bookmark icon?

Tags: javascript, browser, progressive-web-apps

For example on chrome, the WhatsApp Web bookmark icons shows your current message count, Reddit has a red dot and even LinkedIn displays the icon with a blue dot on the top left corner when you have notifications. A point in the right direction on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically change the icon of a favorite by changing the href of favicon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Dynamic favicon</title>
        <link rel="icon" id="favicon" href="./icons/icon_without_dot.png" type="image/png" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Dynamic favicon</h1>
        <button onclick="toggleFavicon()">Change favicon</button>

        <script>
            const favicon = document.getElementById("favicon");

            function toggleFavicon() {
                if (favicon.getAttribute("href") == "./icons/icon_without_dot.png") {
                    favicon.setAttribute("href", "./icons/icon_with_dot.png");
                }else{
                    favicon.setAttribute("href", "./icons/icon_without_dot.png")
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).